# VB.NET hardcoding with obfuscation trouble

Tags: vb.net, obfuscation, hardcode

I need to hardcode a string in my source code and make an "if clause check" to see if the user entered input is the same or not. I am also using EAZfuscator.net for obfuscating the code. 
However, when ı use the obfuscator, I think it changes my hardcoded string and I can not perfrom the check. How can I overcome this problem? Can I use HEX values instead. How can I find the HEX values for string characters? I use webcomverters but can not seem to get the correct characters.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: there are also some encryption libraries in .net so you can store an encrypted string to compare against.

Comment: Does your program work without obfuscating?

Comment: yes, no problems without obfuscation, however I realized that obfuscation causes my progam to get a MAC address from server worng, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861471/server-mac-address-and-obfuscation